# how to determine if a user is online or not using Layer/Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, layer

I am developing an Android chat app using Layer and Parse. I have reached a point where i have to indicate if a friend is online or not. I have read the documentations on their websites but i dont find anything related to online presence. Is there a document that i have not seen? Please share some insight on how to know if a user is online when using Layer/Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create on column inside User table, isonline, and set that flag true and false base on app open and close.

```
        public static final String CLASSNAME = "userclass";
        public static final String USERID = "userid";
        public static final String USERNAME = "username";
        public static final String USERLASTNAME = "lastname";
        public static final String USERONLINE = "isonline";

        public static void setOnline(String userId, boolean isOnline)
        {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(UserDao.CLASSNAME);
            query.whereEqualTo(USERID, userId);
            List<ParseObject> list = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
            try {
                list = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(list.size() == 1)
            {
                ParseObject object = list.get(0);
                if (isOnline) object.put(USERONLINE,1);
                else object.put(USERONLINE,0);
                object.saveInBackground();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. Although this may not cater for internet connectivity changes after a user has signed in, i find it the closest logical solution that i can use to solve my challenge. I will mark it as an answer.